# JavaScript losing whitespace from input

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my problem. I am querying a database to get a number and the text associated with that unique number.

```
<select id="acct" name="acct" onchange="updateAcctnum(this.value, this.id);">
    <option value='None'></option>
    <?php
        $sql = 'select cast(trim(k00001) as char(13) ccsid 37),
            cast(trim(substr(f00001,14-13,31)) as char(13) ccsid 37)
            from QS36F."BD.BMST"
            where cast(trim(substr(f00001,48-13,13)) as char(13) ccsid 37) = 
            '. "'".B001."'" ;
        $result = db2_exec($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = db2_fetch_array($result)) {
            $acctnum = $row[0];
            $acctname = $row[1];
            echo "<option value=" . $acctnum . ">" . $acctname . " -- "
                . $acctnum . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
```

I concatenate row 0 with row 1 to get something like "B001 1 -- Health". This part works fine.
But then i use javascript to get just the number.the $acctnum, or row 0. I'm using this code.

```
function updateAcctnum(val) {
    var actnum = document.getElementById('acct').value;
    document.getElementById('acctnum').value = actnum;
    alert(actnum);
}
```

When this variable gets passed to javascript its losing the space and number after the space. does anyone know what causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
echo "<option value=" . $acctnum . ">";
```

In the outputted HTML that will produce something like `<option value=B001 1>`. You need to quote the value:

```
echo "<option value='" . $acctnum . "'>";
                    ^                ^
```

Comment: You are AWESOME! I knew it was something I wasn't doing correctly. THANK YOU.